# MOSFET switching dissipated power calculation

Tags: power, mosfet

I have a question regarding the calculation of a switching dissipated power of a MOSFET using only `Vdd`, `Id`, `Vgs`, `Vth`, `Fsw` and `Qg` as parameters.

Please tell me if the calculations are correct and/or the formula used.

$$Pd_{sw} = Vd * Id * 0.5 (tsw_{on} + tsw_{off}) * Fsw$$

where

$$tsw_{on} = Qg / Ig_{on} $$ and $$tsw_{off} = Qg / Ig_{off}  $$

For example, for a [IXFK48N50Q](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IXFK48N50Q/IXFK48N50Q-ND/1651955) transistor, `Vdd` 400V, `Id` 10A, `Fsw` 100kHz and using Rg of 10Ω, I get `Ig_on` 1.49A and `Ig_off` 0.51A resulting in `tsw_on` and `tsw_off` to be 98ns, respectively 288ns. 
This results in a `Pd_sw` of almost 80W.

I used PSPICE models from manufacturer and the same parameters as above I only get about 30W of total dissipated power, this means included static.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the switching times in spice match your calculation or are they faster in spice than the datasheet?

Comment: Why is Ig_on so different from Ig_off?

Comment: Here are my formulas for Ig_on and Ig_off: (Vgs - Vth) / Rg and Vth/Rg. My Vgs is 20V, Vth is about 4-5V.

Comment: I just checked, Tsw_on is fairly accurate in spice. tsw_off however is way off.

Comment: Vgs 20V is too high, this is the max rating, use a lower drive voltage like 12V or you could blow the gate oxide. Also, show your ltspice file.

Comment: Here is for another MOSFET, FDP22N50N. Caculated total dissipated power : 35W. Simulated 12W. http://imgur.com/a/pHSOW

Comment: These switching losses are bad but think of it as 2% when 4Kw is referenced to your calculated 80 watt .This is why low frequencies like say 20 to say 30 KHz are still valid .This is why you implement some switching loss reduction scheme .Nowdays the switching losses can and do often exceed the conduction losses because on resistance has come down over the decades and charge has gone up .

Comment: But then, why are the simulated result so different than the calculated one? Can you take a look at my previous comment? Did i do something wrong there?

Comment: If you are using the same formula  and parameters in SPICE, you should be getting the same results as manually! Since you are not, I can only conclude that either the parameters or the formula are not the same.  I also question the use of 0.5 with the time parameters.  I would use only the tswon.

Answer (score 1):

The switching times should be calculated by using the equations

tsw_on = (0.5*Qgs + Qgd) / Ig_on

and

tsw_off = (0.5*Qgs + Qgd) / Ig_off

This way, you will obtain shorter switching times, resulting in lower power dissipation.

There may be further errors in your calculations which I didn't review yet. When I am doing these calculations myself, I like to use Fairchild's Application note AN-6005.

Answer (score 0):

The equation are not exact!. During **switching on** the capacitance of the gate_source, gate_drain, gate_body(substrate) changes. But manufacturer use that equ. in most cases because:

> **When charging a capacitor, half of the energy is dissipated by resistance (parasitic  or 'wanted' resistors)!**

It is also doubtful if the simulation models (sometimes they use very simple Level 2 models!) are correct, from my experience.

Sometimes it is useful to read the [data sheet](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/93001.pdf)!

On page 4 you find this figures:

[image]

You should take this diagram to get the gate-emitter charge, and the other capacitors, then you can compute the energy which is lost per cylce, and then multiply it simply with your frequency, to get the powerdissipation.